# call a java function from js in phonegap

Tags: java, javascript, function, cordova, webintents

I am in mobile app and I have the following problem:

I have `MiniPrinterFunction.java` file inside `com.StarMicronics.StarIOSDK` which contains `GetStatus()`, `PrintText()` and `PrintBitmap()` functions.

I want to call for example `GetStatus()` function from javascript in phonegap.

I try webintent as follows

```
window.plugins.webintent.sendBroadcast({
        action: 'com.StarMicronics.StarIOSDK.MiniPrinterFunctions.GetStatus'

    }, function() {alert("test1");
    }, function() {alert("test2");
});
```

with no success...

Is this the proper way to do this or is there any other way to do this????

please advice

Comment: Have you registered callbacks correctly?

Comment: i am new in this... how can i do this?? Is there any tutorial???